# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse some data I pulled from instagram so I can use gephi to visualize a social graph.

I have an .har file and .json for each account (./data/{person}/following.har) and (./data/{person}/profile.json).

When I try to extract the data into one json file (./out/people.json) I keep getting the error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string at: line 1067001 column 26 (char 87399905)".

The error seems to be occurring at `data = json.loads(f.read())`

I've seen [ftfy](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) as a potential solution, but have not had success.

Here is the code w/o ftfy.

```
import json
import os
import re
import base64

def extract_profile(data) -> list:
return data['graphql']['user']

def extract_followings(data) -> list:
friendship_api_url = r'https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/friendships/.*/following'

contents = [entry['response']['content'] for entry in data['log']['entries']
            if re.match(friendship_api_url, entry['request']['url'])]

# extract json data
users = []
for content in contents:
    if 'text' not in content:
        continue
    text = content['text']

    if 'encoding' in content:
        encoding = content['encoding']
        if encoding == 'base64':
            decodedBytes = base64.b64decode(text)
            decodedStr = str(decodedBytes, 'utf-8')
            user_json = json.loads(decodedStr)
            users.extend(user_json['users'])
    else:
        user_json= json.loads(text)
        users.extend(user_json['users'])
    
return users

def extract_person(person: str):
with open(f'./data/{person}/following.har', 'r', errors='ignore') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    followings = extract_followings(data)

with open(f'./data/{person}/profile.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    profile = extract_profile(data)

output = {
    'general': profile,
    'followings': followings
}
return output, profile['id']

def extract_all():
persons = os.listdir('./data')

users = {}
for person in persons:
    output, id = extract_person(person)
    users[id] = output

with open('./out/people.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(users))

extract_all()
```

Here is line 1067001 column 26 `"url": "https://static.cdninstagram.com/rsrc.php/v3ikSh4/yq/l/en_US/ueR5Vvb4hPlbfkjYLCs4rGemD-jplRG0pz`

Comment: Add line 1067001 of the file to the question.

Comment: Why are you encoding a JSON file with base64? JSON is plain text, it doesn't need to be encoded.

Comment: FYI `json.loads(f.read())` can be written simpler as `json.load(f)`

Comment: The indentation of all your functions is wrong.

Comment: I added line 10067001 to the question. Some things in the json file needed to be encoded. Did not know about json.load(f). Will check indentation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the issue with the line you've posted is that it's missing a closing `"` as the error message indicated

Comment: Yes. The file also did not include the appropriate ending w/ "serverIPAddress":
        "startedDateTime": 
        "time": 
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 
          "dns": 
          "ssl": 
          "connect": 
          "send": 
          "wait": 
          "receive": 
          "_blocked_queueing":

I realized that I had issue loading the followings with this specific account. It wasn't make or break to have it included so I just got rid of it all together. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So the problem is just that the file is incomplete. Obviously that won't work.

Comment: Yes and it turns out I have this problem in other files. Very fun.